# Visual StudioとSQL Serverで複数人で開発する際のデータベースの定義や初期データの管理方法について

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server, entity-framework

こんにちは。
レガシーな（.NET Framework+SQL Server+WinFrom）ローカルアプリをWPF化しています。
その中で、機能拡張や導入ユーザ別のカスタマイズなどが発生しており、データベースの定義情報や設定などの初期データの管理方法でどのようなツール？概念？を使えばよいか困っています。

新規から作成のWebアプリの場合、EntityFrameworkを使い、Code First（もしくは、Model First、DB First）で複数人（10～20人程度）での開発をやってきました。

しかし、今回は、DBが8割できており、Entityの定義はないという条件下で、アジャイル的な変更をチームでかけていきたいのですが、うまくスムーズな共有と開発同期や開発環境の切替などが出来ずにこまっております。

一人で開発をする場合は、個別にローカルのDBにクエリを当てて管理することが出来るのですが、、、多人数で管理するとなると共有の仕組み、切替の仕組みが必要になると考えています。

どのようなよいプラクティス、ツールがありますでしょうか？

考えているのが、Ruby on RailsのDB管理の仕組みを自分で作る？（VersionUP/Down）
もしくは、もっと、単純に適応するクエリをフォルダにバージョンをつけて入れておき、
最新のバージョンになるまで適応する管理を行う？（最新ソースの取得して実行する。）

などで考えています。

## 環境

- Visual Studio 2015～2019
- SQL Server 2016～2017
- WPFアプリ
- ソース管理 git